Raspberry Pi transmitting CSV files using scp not working when in crontab?
So i am trying to send 2 CSV files from one Pi to another Pi for a project. I have done this and it works. shell code below:
called fileTX.sh
#!/bin/bash

password="pword"
username="pi"

ip="111.11.11.1"

while:
do
    sshpass -p "$password" scp myCSV1.csv $username@ip:Desktop/
    sshpass -p "$password" scp myCSV2.csv $username@ip:Desktop/

    echo "Files transmitted!"
    sleep 60

done


again, this works when I execute in the terminal perfectly. But when I add the line of code to do this in crontab, it doesn't work.
the code i put into crontab is:
@reboot /home/me/fileTX.sh &
I know it isn't transmitting because when I edit the csv files on the TX pi, they are not being modified on the RX pi.
I strongly believe the syntax I have in crontab is correct. I used the full file path in crontab to reference the shell script. I've made the script executable.
I have played around with having "@reboot sh/bash/#!/bin/bash /home/me/fileTX.sh &" and none of those variations work. So which is the correct prefix to reference the bash script with?
Is there anything else I'm missing??
i used crontab before for other programs (only python) and it works fine. I don't understand why this isn't working.

no network yet, maybe

The script shown has a syntax error, a missing space between while and :. You should also look in root's mailbox to see what your script outputs (cron sends all output on stdout and stderr to the user's mailbox).

Beside strange while construction (rise error) you have problem with line:
sshpass -p "$password" scp myCSV1.csv $username@ip:Desktop/

You should add $ before ip variable
sshpass -p "$password" scp myCSV1.csv $username@$ip:Desktop/


I did fix this and it still doesn't run in cron... the code runs when i execute in the terminal but wont run w/ cron
